# Using the Hyper-V sockets between Windows host and Linux guest

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, hyper-v

I want to write simple application that communicates between the Hyper-V host and its virtual machine using Hyper-V sockets (netcat over vsock). In the Internet there are a few documents describing how to do it: [Make your own integration services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/make-integration-service), [Practical Hyper-V socket communication](https://w4mhi.wordpress.com/2016/08/29/what-about-hyper-v-socket-communication/). However, any of them helps me to achieve my goal.

First of all, I've made sure that the connection using Hyper-V sockets is possible. On the guest Linux I loaded `hv_sock` module and run [nc-vsock](https://github.com/stefanha/nc-vsock) application which is able to listen on vsocks:

```sh
$ sudo modprobe hv_sock
$ nc-vsock -l 1234
```

On Windows in PowerShell I ran hvc, which utilises Hyper-V sockets and is able to emulate netcat:

```sh
hvc nc -t vsock little-helper 1234
```

and it works. I can see data sent from server to client and vice versa.

Then I wrote a simple application basing on [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/make-integration-service) and [2](https://w4mhi.wordpress.com/2016/08/29/what-about-hyper-v-socket-communication/) with slight changes.
I registered my application with the Hyper-V Host's registry as said in [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/make-integration-service) and I ran my application. The connection was not established and the `connect` function returned error 10049.

I've tried to run my application as a administrator and manipulate GUIDs in the source code and on the Hyper-V Host's registry as well. However, nothing helps and application always reports error 10049.

In my opinion in the document are some ambiguity. E.g. it's said that the service id shall be a random GUID. But later on there is a note that the first four octets translate to port in AF_VSOCK address family, and the specific GUID is presented for this purpose.

Question is rather simple: what I did wrong or misunderstood. Is it possible to write netcat utilising vsock between Windows and Linux?

Full code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <hvsocket.h>

#include <combaseapi.h>

int main()
{
    struct __declspec(uuid("00000000-185c-4e04-985a-4c2eee3e03cc")) VSockTemplate {};
    struct __declspec(uuid("2a9fa68e-4add-45cb-85c8-de97fc66d388")) ServerVsockTemplate {};

    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    SOCKET ConnectSocket;
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_HYPERV, SOCK_STREAM, HV_PROTOCOL_RAW);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.
    SOCKADDR_HV clientService;
    clientService.Family = AF_HYPERV;
    clientService.VmId = __uuidof(ServerVsockTemplate);
    clientService.ServiceId = __uuidof(VSockTemplate);
    clientService.ServiceId.Data1 = 1234;

    //----------------------
    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"connect function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        iResult = closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    wprintf(L"Connected to server.\n");

    iResult = closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the `ServerVsockTemplate` GUID you have there? I'm pretty sure that's supposed to be the GUID of a running VM, e.g., `(Get-VM -Name $VMName).Id`, so it'd be hard to hard-code into your source. If that's the GUID you generated per ['Register a new application'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/make-integration-service#register-a-new-application), that'll be the problem.

The docs aren't clear, but I have the strong suspicion that 'Register a new application' part is only for when you're listening on Windows for incoming connections from other Windows VMs, or when writing a Linux device driver that talks to a service on the host. It might also be to allow a VM to offer services to other VMs, but I would assume not.

Edit: [Quick Testing VSOCK (Hyper-V) Support in X410](https://x410.dev/cookbook/hyperv/quick-testing-vsock-hyper-v-support-in-x410/) says you need to make the registry keys for the vsock GUIDs as well, to receive connections from the vm.

In Linux userspace, you only have access to vsock; the [other services](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d3590ebf6f91350192737dd1d1b219c05277f067/include/linux/hyperv.h#L1248-L1399) are managed by drivers under Linux.

There's a clearer explanation of the vsock workflow in the Linux source for the [Hyper-V vsock implementation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d3590ebf6f91350192737dd1d1b219c05277f067/net/vmw_vsock/hyperv_transport.c#L109-L148).

I assume it's possible to use VSock between a Windows VM and the host as well, of course.

---

Edit, because I actually went and tested this.

Two mistakes in the code, on top of the `ServerVsockTemplate` GUID needing to be the GUID of the target VM.

- The `VSockTemplate` GUID is wrong. I don't know where that came from, but there's a constant `HV_GUID_VSOCK_TEMPLATE` in `<hvsocket.h>` anyway, which matches the one on the Microsoft Docs site: `00000000-facb-11e6-bd58-64006a7986d3`
- It turns out, you need to zero the `Reserved` member of the `SOCKADDR_HV`, or it'll fail. Traditionally, one would use `memset` to zero a new `sockaddr_*` structure, but in this case, we can take the easy path.

So to make this work, change the `SOCKADDR_HV` creation code to the following:

```
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.
    SOCKADDR_HV clientService;
    clientService.Family = AF_HYPERV;
    clientService.Reserved = 0;
    clientService.VmId = __uuidof(ServerVsockTemplate);
    clientService.ServiceId = HV_GUID_VSOCK_TEMPLATE;
    clientService.ServiceId.Data1 = 1234;
```

Then you delete `VSockTemplate`, and make sure `ServerVsockTemplate` is the GUID of the VM or Micro-VM where you're running nc-vsock.

I actually tested this with the WSL2 micro-VM, for which the VM ID comes from `hcsdiag list` rather than `Get-VM`, but I was able to connect to `nc-vsock` inside my WSL2 session using the source here, modified as I have described.

Answer (score 3):

For whoever is not very familiar with Hyper-V and does not want to spend 2 hours debugging, like I did, a few points:

Ensure that the **hv_sock** kernel module is enabled on the guest, I used Ubuntu Server 20.04, which does not have this enabled by default.

```bash
lsmod | grep hv_sock
```

If it's not there you need to add it and reboot:

```bash
sudo sh -c 'echo "hv_sock" > /etc/modules-load.d/hv_sock.conf'
sudo reboot
```

You **need** to register a new application with Hyper-V Host's registry, but the docs are misleading, as the random GUID is only needed with a Windows guest, for Linux guests the GUID needs to be in a very specific format, as described by **HV_GUID_VSOCK_TEMPLATE**, meaning `<port>-facb-11e6-bd58-64006a7986d3`

So for port `5001` the registry key should be `00001389-facb-11e6-bd58-64006a7986d3` (1389 is 5001 in hex)
You can do that easily from powershell as described in the [Register a new application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/make-integration-service#register-a-new-application) section

```psh
$service = New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtualization\GuestCommunicationServices" -Name "00001389-facb-11e6-bd58-64006a7986d3"
$service.SetValue("ElementName", "HV Socket Demo")
```

You can find some simple code samples [here](https://github.com/Biswa96/wslbridge2/tree/master/samples), **win_server.c** for the Windows host and **wsl_client.c** for the Linux guest.

Comment: That step about registering with Hyper-V host's registry is so critical. Saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Note that this step is not needed if the HvSocket server is on WSL end and the client is on Windows host end.